# UITableViewCell not updating UISwitch when selecting row

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a `UITableViewCell` that contains a bunch of `UISwitches`. I want the switch to toggle on/off based on what row the user selects, the data is passing to my cell but the switch state is not updating.

I am using a basic MVC, the Storyboard has a TableView > TableViewCell > Label | UISwitch

Controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

var testList = [1,2,3,4,5]
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    table.tableFooterView = UIView()
    table.delegate = self
    table.dataSource = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return testList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseCell") as! SwitchCell
    //Turn them all on at start
    cell.setSwitch(rowSelected: true)
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseCell") as! SwitchCell
    cell.setSwitch(rowSelected: false)
}

}
```

SwitchCell

class SwitchCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var uiswitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

func setCell(number: Int){
    label.text = String(number)
}

func setSwitch(rowSelected:Bool) {
    uiswitch.setOn(rowSelected, animated: true)
}

}
```

I know I can just make the UISwitch intractable, but I am looking at changing it's state when the user selects the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseCell") as! SwitchCell
    cell.setSwitch(rowSelected: false)
}
```

is incorrect. Using this code you don't pick the cell you want.

You should do simething like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! SwitchCell
    cell.setSwitch(rowSelected: false)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, we don't dequeue the `cell` in `didSelectRowAt` method. Never do that. This will dequeue a brand new cell and won't reflect any changes that you do in it.

So remove the code for `tableView(_: didSelectRowAt:)` method.

Secondly, you can simply handle the `UISwitch` state based on cell selection  in `SwitchCell's` definition using **`setSelected(_:animate:)`** method like so,

```
class SwitchCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var uiswitch: UISwitch!

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        uiswitch.setOn(selected, animated: true)
    }

    //rest of the code...
}
```

To avoid bulky code, do all the `cell` layout in custom `cell` itself instead of doing it in the `delegate` or `dataSource` methods. That will only make you `ViewController` heavier and non-modular.